# How to identify default Java heapsize in Windows

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

Im running an eclipse application in my machine. I have two queries

1. I would like to know how to check the default heap size that the jvm is using to run the application.I'm using a windows machine to run the java application. I tried to check the default heap size by the following way

> ControlPanel--->Programs--->JavaSetting--> JavaTab -->View Button
>   ---> JavaRuntimeEnvironment settings window ---> Userstab --> Value under RuntimeParameters

But in my system, there is no runtime parameters defined. Is there a command that I can execute via command prompt to check the default heap size in my machine.

2. How to increase the heap size parameter and run the eclipse plugin application from  command prompt. 
   For eg:  To increase the heap size and execute the jar file we use the below command 
   `java -Xms64m -jar MyApp.jar`. I would like to know how to set heap parameters and execute my java application which is an `exe` file.  I tried to execute use the below command, but the command prompt doesn't recognize the command

   java -Xms512m iepsd.exe

Where `iepsd.exe` is my java application.

Comment: How do you create the exe file?

Comment: The java application which we are using is an eclipse based application. When we try to export the jar file,the build gets exported as an .exe file.

Comment: Somewhere in the build file of the project you should be able to set parameters the exe will pass to the jvm. Try looking in the docs of the "exe generator" library you use.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` to print out a huge list of internal options to the JVM once all command line arguments and defaults have been processed. The `-Xms` option corresponds to InitialHeapSize, and the `-Xmx` option corresponds to MaxHeapSize.

To find the default maximum heap size that the JVM is using on Windows, run:

```
javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"
```

To find the default initial heap size, run:

```
javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I tried to execute the above command'javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize"' in the command prompt, the value is not getting displayed. Im getting a popup message which says, could not create the java Virtual Machine

Comment: If you're getting an error just running javaw then you've got some sort of installation or configuration problem. What is the exact error message in the dialog? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Please tell me, the value returned after hitting the above command... unit ? Is it byte or KB ? Thanks. I hope it is 'byte'

Comment: I assume the units are bytes, but it would be very easy to determine. Just try some different -Xmx options and see how they affect the result. -Xmx1G should set the max heap size to 10615783424 bytes, for example.

Comment: I have tried : C:\Users\Administrator>javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"
"Could not create java virtual machine" error is prompting in Windows Server. 
What is the mistake I have made?

Comment: I can confirm it is in bytes

Answer (score 11):

try below command for detailed result

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
```

result is

```
C:\Users\amar.magar>java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 268435456                           {product}
uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 4271898624                          {product}
 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 0                                   {pd product}
 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 0                                   {pd product}

java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer the below query of `vr3w3c9`

**Query raised by `vr3w3c9`**:
Hi, Thanks for the response. I tried to execute the above command `javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize"` in the command prompt, the value is not getting displayed. Im getting a popup message which says:

> could not create the java Virtual Machine –  vr3w3c9 Sep 27 '13 at 4:54

**Answer:** In Windows machine, Please run/open the Command Prompt (Windows Command Processor) **as Administrator** and execute the command you have mentioned. you will get the result as shown below:

```
C:\windows\system32>javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"

uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 2122317824      {product}

C:\windows\system32>javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize"

uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 132531136       {product}
```

Here, the **unit** of MaxHeapSize and InitialHeapSize is **bytes**.

Comment: I have tried the same but still getting the error saying "Could not create java virtual machine"

Answer (score 1):

Use JConsole. It is shipped with the JDK. You will find it's executable in the corresponding bin directory.

Comment: Can you please eloborate on the same.Once I click the jconsole.exe file, it opens a console. Not sure how to proceed and how to identify the default heap size

Comment: Your java process will be listed under local processes. Connect to it. After connecting you will have a lot of options including heap dump, thread dump etc. You will also know the exact division of your heap space like how much is perm gen etc.Jconsole is buggy and you may not always be able to connect to your process. i personally use **jvisualvm**. But i know it in Linux. You may want to search the same for Windows(you have to install it separately)

Answer (score 0):

Map JDK, usually in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.xx.xx\bin\jconsole". Open jconsole app, you can now monitor and manage JVM.