# Defining Java Heap Size for All Users on a Windows System

Tags: java, heap-size

I am relatively new to Java we are running Java 8 JRE Update 211 32bit on Windows 10 PC and Server 2019 and I am trying to define heap size for all users who login to the PCs/Servers.

I know the Java is out of date but the Java has been suggested by Application providers and our network is closed off to the internet and really locked down.

I have done some googling seems like you can define this in the Deployment.properties file (located in C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment) currently I have this:

```
deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-xms1024M

deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-xmx3072M

deployment.javaws.jre.0.args=-xmn512M
```

I do know that maximum you can define 2GB on 32bit systems.

I am unable to find any Java forums or help on these commands I found some on the internet and tweaked them I wanted to know if these are correct above?

[image: Java Error on Client System]

We have been advised from the application side (Cramer) the heap size has doubled and still getting this message.

Edit Added:

Unable to do this from the Java Control Panel as the system tab area is greyed out:

[image: Java Control Panel]

Also ran the commands:

**javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"**

**javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "InitialHeapSize"**

Found that the Java has not picked up the changes that have been defined in the deployment.properties file:

[image: Java command output]

I believe the digits outputted above are in bytes which converting them to MBs doesn't match the values I defined.

Comment: Well, I would start with verifying whether your settings are IN FACT applied, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19028297/how-to-identify-default-java-heapsize-in-windows for example. If so: maybe that "Cramer client" software that gives you trouble ... isn't designed to run on a system that has limitations?

Comment: Beyond that, it is not really clear what your question is. And note: administrating windows machines isnt exactly a programming question, and thus off topic here.

Comment: Also keep in mind that Java 8 is basically end of life and higher versions will still be able to run applications compiled against Java 8 (assuming this is why you've picked this version)

Comment: @GhostCat I have added some edits please see above, my question is clear in the heading all I need is guidance on how to set Java Heap Size for all users on a Windows System I can't do this via the Java Control panel (which is explained above and also explained why we are using a certain version of Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

So, first thing I did was remove definitions of heap sizes I added to the deployment.properties file.

I had to create a system variable called:

`Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS`

`Variable value: -Xmx512M`

Also, had to add to the PATH Variable Java bin folder location:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin**

Then rebooted the server and when I entered the following command:

**javaw -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal | find "MaxHeapSize"**

Then I saw the Max Heap size was set to 512MB for all users which is what I was trying to achieve.

I didn't want to start messing about with the initial heap size settings as this was causing a few issues.

Now I can foresee another issue I need to resolve is how to define different Max Heap Sizes for 32bit and 64bit Java's install on one Operation System.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have the JRE installed in the system through an installer.
If this is the case, go to Control Settings and select show small icons:

[image]

There you have java settings. Click on it and you will be greeted with a settings window for your JRE. Go to the Java Tab and then click display.

[image]

Add on runtime parameters the parameters you need (e.g. `-Xmx3072M`). You can choose whether you want to do that for the Users or for the whole system (hence the tabs).

Comment: Unable to add this way (I should of added this to the question above) I have done now but the area is greyed out and I have ran the application as an administrator. Correct I have JRE installed via a Windows installer.